# Spark UDF not working: how to specify the column on which to apply it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Let's say I have my DataFrame, with a given column named "X". I want to understand why the first code doesn't work whereas the second one does. For me, it doesn't change anything.

On the one hand, this doesn't work:

```
val dataDF = sqlContext
      .read
      .parquet(input_data)
      .select(
          "XXX", "YYY", "III"
      )
      .toDF(
          "X", "Y", "I"
      )
      .groupBy(
          "X", "Y"
      )
      .agg(
          sum("I").as("sum_I")
      )
      .orderBy(desc("sum_I"))
      .withColumn("f_sum_I", udf((x: Long) => f(x)).apply(dataDF("sum_I")))
      .drop("sum_I")

dataDF.show(50, false)
```

IntelliJ doesn't compile my code and I have the following error:

```
Error:(88, 67) recursive value dataDF needs type
      .withColumn("f_sum_I", udf((x: Long) => f(x)).apply(dataDF("sum_I")))
```

On the other hand, this work if I change the given line with this:

```
.withColumn("f_sum_I", udf((x: Long) => f(x)).apply(col("sum_I")))
```

All I did was replacing the call to my DataFrame column to use a more generic function "col". I don't understand the difference, and more especially why does it not prefer the first method (with the name of the DataFrame).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use `dataDF` before you're done defining it - `dataDF` is the result of the entire expression starting with `sqlContext.read` and ending with `.drop("sumI")`, so you can't use it within that expression.

You can solve this by simply referencing the column without using the DataFrame, e.g. using the `col` function from `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`:

```
.withColumn("f_sum_I", udf((x: Long) => f(x)).apply(col("sum_I")))
```